# How to test rollback of transaction in Hibernate+Spring+JUnit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, transactions

I am trying to test the mechanism of rollbackin transaction in cases of somthing went wrong. I read many similar topics, but nothing helps me. Here is what i try:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/rest-servlet.xml" })
@Transactional
public class TagDaoImplTest extends DatabaseTestCase {

    private static final String FLAT_XML_DATASET = "FlatXmlDataSet.xml";

    @Autowired
    private TagDao tagDao;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        DatabaseOperation.REFRESH.execute(getConnection(), getDataSet());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddWithRollback() throws Exception {
        addWithRollback("testTagToAdd"); //i suppouse that we tried to add, but somthing went wrong and transaction was rolled back
        final Tag testTagToAdd = tagDao.findByTag("testTagToAdd"); // so db must be without changes and i check this
        assertNull(testTagToAdd);
    }

    @Rollback(true) //i want this method to rollback after its work to imitate corrupted transaction
    private void addWithRollback(String tag) throws Exception {
        tagDao.add(new Tag(tag));
    }
}
```

My dao looks like this:

```
@Repository("tagDao")
public class TagDaoImpl implements TagDao {

    @Override
    public void add(Tag tag) {
        final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(tag);
    }
}
```

But my test fails because it finds that tag in db (and this means transaction wasn`t rolled back). I tried many different things like get current session and transaction and manually invoke rollback, but nothing happend. Can you please help me?

Comment: you actually have a method that makes the rollback? or if a method has an error/exception it executes the standard hibernate rollback? (last one does not make much sense, hibernate rollback is already tested, but can be easily done simply throwing the required exception)

Comment: I`ve also tried to throw exception in dao class, to make the transaction rollback, but it still can find added tag.

Comment: Execution of your test is in a single transaction that will rollback (or commit) after the execution of testAddWithRollback

Comment: Ok, but why therefore sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback() doesn`t do anything and I still can read added tag? However, how can I change it, to run every single methot in its on transaction, and test that rollback is performed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for me it feels a bit weird that you try to test the repository layer. Normally there should not be any business logic, thus this means that you try to test Hibernate or SQL which are already tested million of times and there is no point of doing it.

I would suggest to annotate your method with something like this:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
```

and maybe specify the Exception. Then in the test you prepare your system in a way that this method throws this exception. Thus it should be rolled back and no data should be changed.

Furthermore, I would like to add that actually loading spring context at this point most probably is different compare to the production one. Thus this is an additional point where I would say that there is no point of doing it. At least on the repository layer.